# Is there a way to run tasks on failure without block/rescue?

Tags: ansible

I'd like to run some *code* (e.g. a task) when a task fails. The only way I've found to do this is using `block`s.

The `block`/`rescue` method works for my use case, but it's forcing an (otherwise) unnecessary keyword in my playbook.

Is there a way to rewrite the below:

```
- name: my play
  hosts: 127.0.0.0
  any_errors_fatal: true
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: install something and configure that thing
      block:
        - name: install something
          shell: install something
        - name: configure that something
          shell: do some things
      rescue:
        - name: rollback
          shell: uninstall that thing
```

To something where I don't use `block`? either by with `rescue` (if it is possible to use rescue without block?) or by another means. Something like:

```
- name: my play
  hosts: 127.0.0.0
  any_errors_fatal: true
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: install something
      shell: install something
    - name: configure that something
      shell: do some things
      rescue:
        - name: rollback
          shell: uninstall that thing
```

?

Comment: for your consideration: it's not unnecessary, it's scoping the width of the `try` for the `except` action; if you just want to rescue **one** task, then do what gary lopez says and use `ignore_errors: yes` along with `register:`, but you're really swimming upstream at that point when ansible provides a dedicated mechanism which is actually less characters that coding that `rescue:` behavior by hand

Answer (score 2):

There isn't way to do that. Rescue is exclusive of block, you could save a variable with `register` in your first task and execute other task with `when` if the variable was false but I guess it's better use block instead this way.